# Determine File Exists using getFileStreamPath--sorta working

Tags: android

I am trying to determine if a file exists in my app folder on the sdcard. I check for the folder existence first and handle that just fine. Next I want to see if the file exists so I tried the following but got the "contains a path seperator"

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(ChildFolder + "/LiftData.xml");
```

ChildFolder is the correct path. I set it earlier and you can see it correctly in the debug perspective. If I use just the file name it does not see the file and creates it everytime.

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("LiftData.xml");
```

I suspect this is because without any path info it is looking for the file in the root. I could set the base context but would that work and is it proper / good practice?

I'm not finding any good examples when I ask Google for help so I apologize for bothering you again to help this Java noob.

JB

Comment: use File constructor. It does not require context to be instantiated: File file  = new File(ChildFolder, "LiftData.xml");

Comment: Fair enough. When / what situation would I use context?

Comment: for situation like this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29 , IMO

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- To obtain the application's folder on the external storage, call [`Context.getExternalFilesDir`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).
- Instead of using "/", use the constant `File.separator` (or, better yet, use the `File` constructor to assemble the absolute path: `File(basePath, "LiftData.xml")`
- Test for file existance with [`File.exists`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#exists())
- Keep in mind that your app needs explicit permission to access external storage, and that you should check if it is available via [`Environment.getExternalStorageState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState())